# Problem with performance when comparing and joining text files line by line

Tags: python-3.x, performance, text, nlp

I attach my google collabolatory script. It does what it is supposed to do, but it works very slow, much too slow. So slow, that collab cannot process the file in reasonable time. The code is supposed to do just simple comparison of two files an based on that join other files. It also consumes tones of RAM. Can you help optimize it so that it works fast.

Here is my code:

```
#@title Download and extract files.
!wget "https://object.pouta.csc.fi/OPUS-CCAligned/v1/moses/en-uk.txt.zip"
!wget "https://object.pouta.csc.fi/OPUS-CCAligned/v1/moses/en-pl.txt.zip"
!7z e "en-pl.txt.zip" -o"enpl"
!7z e "en-uk.txt.zip" -o"enuk"
```

```
#@title Do the task.
from tqdm import tqdm

def readlines_from_path(path, encoding="utf-8"):
    with open(path, "r", encoding=encoding) as reader:
        return reader.readlines()


english_polish_pl = readlines_from_path("enpl/CCAligned.en-pl.pl")
english_polish_en = readlines_from_path("enpl/CCAligned.en-pl.en")

english_ukranian_uk = readlines_from_path("enuk/CCAligned.en-uk.uk")
english_ukranian_en = readlines_from_path("enuk/CCAligned.en-uk.en")


for english, polish in tqdm(zip(english_polish_en, english_polish_pl), total=len(english_polish_en)):
    
    if english not in english_ukranian_en:
        continue

    index = english_ukranian_en.index(english)
  
    with open("pl-uk.pl", "a", encoding="utf-8") as writer:
        writer.write(polish)

    with open("pl-uk.uk", "a", encoding="utf-8") as writer:
        writer.write(english_ukranian_uk[index])
```

The problem is that it works super slow, for these files shows more than 800h

Answer (score 0):

The are several issue in this code. The biggest one is that the **complexity of the algorithm is quadratic** (ie. `O(n²)`). Since the input files contains several million lines, this means dozens of million billion string comparison. The fact that is takes a lot of memory is certainly due to the input file having a size close to 1 GiB each and CPython is not particularly designed for this use-case.

You can solve the performance issue by converting `english_ukranian_uk` to a **dictionary** so to know the index of the key in `O(1)`. This means a bigger memory footprint but a script many order of magnitude faster.

Another issue is that `pl-uk.pl` and `pl-uk.uk` are continuously reopened while they can be opened only once. Opening+closing a file is a bit expensive since it does multiple system calls. Doing this several million times is not reasonable.